# Is there a trigger that fires by changing a row?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there any option to run a function in my google-spreadsheet triggered by changing the row only (means setting the cursor in a new cell)? 
The Script-Guide of Google describes only the following `ChangeTypes`:

```
EDIT
INSERT_ROW
INSERT_COLUMN
REMOVE_ROW
REMOVE_COLUMN
INSERT_GRID
REMOVE_GRID
FORMAT
OTHER
```

I am looking for a Trigger like `CHANGE_ROW`.

Comment: Did you already considered to use the On Edit simple or installable triggers? By the way, IMHO in Google Apps Script lingo, "changing" the selected cell isn't not being called a change.

Answer (score 1):

No, a user moving the cursor around does not create an event for any trigger in Google Sheets.

The best you can do is run a timed trigger than [gets Active Cell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getActiveCell()) and compares the row value with the one [stored previously](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service). But this is unlikely to have satisfactory performance, because a timed script can't run more often than once a minute (and if you try to keep it running in a loop, it will hit [execution time quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)).